# Why part of the script cannot execute in the crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a script stopping the application and zipping some files:

`/home/myname/project/stopWithZip.sh`

With the properties below:

`-rwxrwxr-x. 1 myname myname778 Jun 25 13:48 stopWithZip.sh`

Here is the content of the script:

```
ps -ef | grep project | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -15

month=`date +%m`
year=`date +%Y`

fixLogs=~/project/log/fix/$year$month/*.log.*
errorLogs=~/project/log/error/$year$month/log.*

for log in $fixLogs
do
  if [ ! -f "$log.gz" ];
  then
    gzip $log
    echo "Archived:"$log
  else
    echo "skipping" $log
  fi
done
echo "Archived fix log files done"


for log in $errorLogs
do
  if [ ! -f "$log.gz" ]; then
    gzip $log
    echo "Archived:"$log
  else
    echo "skipping" $log
  fi
done
echo "Archived errorlog files done"
```

The problem is except this `ps -ef | grep project | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' |xargs  kill -15` command, other gzip commands are not executed. I totally don't understand why.

I cannot see any compression of the logs in the directory.

BTW, when I execute the `stopWithZip.sh` explicitly in command line, it works perfectly fine.

In crontab：

`00 05 * * 2-6 /home/myname/project/stopWithZip.sh >> /home/myname/project/cronlog/$(date +"\%F")-stop.log 2>&1` (NOT work)

In command line:

`/home/myname/project>./stopWithZip.sh` (work)

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script fails when run under `cron` because your script is invoked with `project` in its path, so the `kill` pipeline kills the script too.

You could prove (or disprove) this by adding some tracing.  Log the output of `ps` and of `awk` to log files:

```
ps -ef |
tee /tmp/ps.log.$$ |
grep project |
grep -v grep |
awk '{print $2}' |
tee /tmp/awk.log.$$ |
xargs kill -15
```

Review the logs and see that your script is one of the processes being killed.

---

The `crontab` entry contains:

```
/home/myname/project/stopWithZip.sh >> /home/myname/project/cronlog/$(date +"\%F")-stop.log 2>&1
```

When `ps` lists that, it contains 'project' and does not contain 'grep' so the `kill` in the script kills the script itself.

When you run it from the command line (using a conventional '`$`' as the prompt), you run:

```
$ ./stopWithZip.sh
```

and when `ps` lists that, it does not contain 'project' so it is not killed.

If you ran:

```
$ /home/myname/project/stopWithZip.sh >> /home/myname/project/cronlog/$(date +"\%F")-stop.log 2>&1
```

from the command line, like you do with `cron` (`crontab`), you would find it fails.

Comment: Plz see my update: when I execute the `stopWithZip.sh` explicitly in command line, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Show me the crontab entry and show me the command line (edit them into the question — do not add them as a comment here, please).  Then I'll show you why one works and the other doesn't (or let you know that I don't have an explanation).  But I'm confident that with your crontab entry and your command line, the explanation will be simple.

Comment: Your 'command line' is shown as: `/home/myname/project>./stopWithZip.sh` which I think has to be interpreted as 'current directory is `/home/myname/project` and the `>` marks the end of the prompt so the command being run is just `./stopWithZip.sh`, which is a name that does not contain `project` so it works.  If you ran `$PWD/stopWithZip.sh` (more nearly simulating what `cron` does), you'd find it failed.  See my update to my answer, which says much the same thing.

Comment: Personally, my prompt always ends with a blank, and usually a `:` before it (for example, on my machine 'osiris', my prompt is '`Osiris JL: `').  I don't like echo the current directory; I work in directories where the pathname is almost as wide as a 100-column screen, and it annoys the living daylights out of me to have my commands printed over in the right margin of the screen.  So, I always set my prompt to something sane and short, and ending with a space.

Comment: I understand your answer now. Is it easier to put the zip operation as a separate command in the crontab?

Comment: I'd probably just make sure the command isn't killed; adding `grep -v $0` into the pipeline should do the trick.